# Permission problems with file transfer from filezilla runs into login problems in the shopware backend / frontend

Tags: debian, virtualbox, bitnami, shopware

I have running a shopware stack on AWS which runs without problems.
Now I try to clone this live shop to an development environment using bitnami shopware stack for **virtualbox**.

I have connected this virtual stack of shopware via SSH and PPk Key to putty as well as filezilla.

Now I tried to upload my live direktory "shopware" to overwrite the existing shopware folder on virtual machines `opt/bitnami/apps`

After I went in this error:

[image: error]

I read in the community to change user an group-user to bitnami:

`sudo chown -c bitami /opt/bitnami/apps`

It still isn´t working but another big problem is ahead:

I don´t reach my login and frontend site on virtual machine, there´s now this error:

> You don't have permission to access /backend on this server.

Before this user was changed it works with login via browser, there was the user `root`, so I tried to give this user back, but the problem is also there:

[image: user change]

I hope anyone can tell me the following two questions:

1.) How I have to change the permissions / Users back, that I can login via browser in shopware

2.) How I have to modify the permissions to upload local shopware folder (including all sub folders) to `opt/bitnami/apps` on virtual machine.

Thank you very much for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

First of all you are trying to access `/opt/bitnami/apps/shopware/shopware/htdocs` when the real path is `/opt/bitnami/apps/shopware/htdocs`. Apart from that, it seems you removed the execution permissions of the files under /opt/bitnami/apps/shopware and that's why you can't list the content of the folder.

```
apps/shopware/htdocs:
total 380
drw-rw-rw- 12 bitnami daemon   4096 Jan 15 04:08 .
```

Please use a SSH connection and run this command

```
sudo chmod +x /opt/bitnami/apps/shopware/*
```

Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

1.) This might be a false setting on your virtual host. Please make sure that the server will use the .htaccess provided by shopware (e.g. "AllowOverride All") and mod_rewrite is activated. Since /backend is not a folder/file, this shouldn't be an issue with permissions. (if shopware.php/backend will work, it's an issue with mod_rewrite)

2.) You need to check if the user running the apache process is "bitnami" or another one. This is a common user rights and permissions issue. You are using a different user to create those files (via FTP) and a second one (the one who runs the apache process) to access it. You need to make sure, that both users can create and access those files (e.g. by using the same group).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. shopware.php/backend isn´t working too --> "403 - forbitten". unfortunately I actually have no permissions for reading the folder htdocs on server still the ssh connection is valid...So I have to look for solving the permission issues. All these problems started with entry the following lines on server console via putty: sudo chown -c bitnami /opt/bitnami/apps